# What is considered a session in the temporary tables

Tags: mysql, procedure, temp-tables

Hi i have while loop with call in it.

```sql
WHILE i<counter DO
    CALL procedure(id, i);
    SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
```

And in CALL:

```sql
BEGIN
DECLARE id, i INT DEFAULT -1;
SELECT * FROM some_joined_table WHERE some_joined_table.id=id LIMIT i,1;
END;
```

I want to union those data from SELECT and for that purpouse I've done temporary table but I have a suspicion that because of the fact that I'm connecting through one connection string this table is shared becouse i received error saying that i can't create 'tmp_table' becouse is already exist.
What should i do?

edit:
I have web page in PHP and all connections are the result of user clicks and are transferred via the connection string through the backend to the database. In one of the views I have to display a certain number (user decides) of rows and perform calculations for each value of this row.
In order to do this, I read the following rows and do the calculations returning them in the form of tables with the same and known number of columns (each is the same) but they contain repetitions and as a result I need one table without repetitions so making a union on them would be perfect.

In oracle or mssql i could just make a union of table return functions but mysql doesn't support table type in functions.

Comment: It's not the connection string that matters, it's the actual connection. Since we have no clue why you create a temp table and how you use it, nor how you connect to the db, we cannot really help you. We can obviously suggest generic solutions, such as consider not using a temp table, but I doubt that this is what you are after.

Comment: I've added some information, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: The updates do not really help.

Comment: What info You need then? In my opinion it's clear enough.

Comment: The question is clear, just not detailed enough to give you a specific answer. I cannot tell based on a high level description if you could avoid the use of temp tables.